# What is the correct type for a prop that can be used in jsx?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have a prop that I will use JSX on it, and I need to define it's type.

```
interface CustomComponentProps {
    Component: // What should I put here?
}

const CustomComponent = ({ Component }: CustomComponentProps) => {
    // some other stuff

    return <Component someProp={foo} />
}
```

What is the type for a prop that can be used with jsx?

Comment: I would recommend a [`React.ReactNode`](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#useful-react-prop-type-examples).

Comment: @zero298 It's not a ReactNode, it's a component. Try `React.ComponentType<PropsType>`

Comment: @zero298 it says `// best, accepts everything` but what is that everything? Because I don't want it to accept something like `<CustomComponent Component={<div>this is wrong</div>} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `React.ComponentType<T>` which accepts both `React.FC` and `React.Component`:

```
interface CustomComponentProps {
    Component: React.ComponentType<{ someProp: string }>
}
```